# Can't call Html.HiddenFor from within my HtmlHelper. Why?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have an HtmlHelper like this: (simplified for clarity)

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, object>> expressionId)
{
    // do something here

    tagBuilder.Append(htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expressionId));

    // do something here
}
```

What happens is that the code works fine when `expressionId` returns `string`. But when it returns `int`, `Html.HiddenFor` trigger this error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I don't know exactly what the problem is, but I suspect it has something to do with this:
When I inspect `expressionId` in debug mode, I can see the expression is: `m => Convert(m.Id)` instead of the expected `m => m.Id`.

What bugs me is that, `MyHelper` is receiving the exact same argument type as `HiddenFor`. So why can't I repass that argument?

What should I do?

**PS**

I'm not passing any nullable expression into MyHelper (I've seen some other questions in which this was the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the cast expression of the non-nullable type.

Try using a strongly typed helper instead of `object`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expressionId
)
{
    // do something here

    tagBuilder.Append(htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expressionId));

    // do something here
}
```

Comment: But this is exactly what I did!

Comment: Oh no, your argument looks like this `Expression<Func<TModel, object>>` which is not what I said in my answer. In my answer I added a second generic argument to your helper. Look closer.